# Good way to Implement Index and Avoid Index to slow down Table

Tags: sql

Im using Execution plan on my querys one by one and in result panel the Green line suggesting
index most of the time.
should i give the table missing index ?

my table Architecture is like :

```
field1   field2    field3   field4            field5       field6    
ID       UserID    HitDate  UserLocationID    UserBrowser  UserIP
```

field types :

```
ID -> Int(PK_AI)
UserID->INT
HitDate->DateTime
UserLocationID->NvarChar
UserBrowser->NvarChar
UserIP->Char
```

On this table i only have Insert And Select. (no Update o Delete at all)
in Execution plan each query suggest different type of Index Like:

```
Non Clustered on HitDate include UserLocationID
```

or

```
Non Clustered on (UserIP,HitDate)
```

or
...

should i build all suggested Index ?
is building all of them have impact on speed of program ? Slower Insert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one index wont slow inserts down much. Adding 10 or 20 will have a impact on inserts. Add one index measure the difference in speed then remove it. Add the other index one measure the difference speed then remove.

Compare notes and then decide. You need to make a educated/informed decision.

Comment: If i add suggested , most of Select query goes for 3 minute respond to 20-30 second. now how can i  messure the impact on slowing the insert query?

Comment: Like I said the impact with one index will be minimal. DONT even worry about that. If the SELECT query is that much faster then it is a win. The inserts will only start slowing down when you have multiple indexes.

Comment: Then i guess i should add the suggested index one by one and then checking the slowdown impact on db. thanks :)

Comment: Correct. There is no right answer with this only a successful strategy. With query optimization it is about finding a balance.

Comment: @nooob you might want to read this answer of mine to help you understand some differences between indexes. See this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18528/performance-difference-between-clustered-and-non-clustered-index/18531#18531